# Google Apps Script to protect range based on dates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to make a google script to protect a range in google sheets based on dates

I want to protect all the rows that its date is 14 days before today

this is the code I have so far,

```
    function ProtectEntradas() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheetEntradas = ss.getSheetByName('Entradas')
  var dateRange = sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 1, sheetEntradas.getLastRow() - 2, 1);
  var val = dateRange.getDisplayValues();
  var date = new Date();
  var protectDateRaw = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - 14);
  var protectDate = Utilities.formatDate(protectDateRaw, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd-MMM-YY");
  var protectRow;
  //check if date is less than the current date
  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i][0] >= protectDate) {
      protectRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  var protection = sheetEntradas.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

  //If protection exists, update else add new one.
  if (protection.length > 0) {
    var range = sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 1, protectRow, 10);
    protection[0].setRange(range);
  }

  else {
    sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 1, protectRow, 10).protect();
  }
```

it is doing some protection, but not the range im expecting

what im I doing wrong ?

[image]

then I want to make a trigger to run every day so it will be protecting the range dinamically

Thanks in advance

Comment: you do not compare dates correctly, use instead format yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to compare correctly dates (3 lignes of code has been modified)

```
function ProtectEntradas() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheetEntradas = ss.getSheetByName('Entradas')
  var dateRange = sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 1, sheetEntradas.getLastRow() - 2, 1);
  // #### modification on how to fetch dates
  var val = dateRange.getValues().map(d => Utilities.formatDate(d[0], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  var date = new Date();
  var protectDateRaw = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - 14);
  // #### modification of the format
  var protectDate = Utilities.formatDate(protectDateRaw, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"); 
  var protectRow;
  //check if date is less than the current date
  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    // #### modification
    if (val[i] >= protectDate) { 
      protectRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  var protection = sheetEntradas.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  //If protection exists, update else add new one.
  if (protection.length > 0) {
    var range = sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 1, protectRow, 10);
    protection[0].setRange(range);
  }
  else {
    sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 1, protectRow, 10).protect();
  }
}
```

edit : if you want to add another criterion, you will have to protect each row (or group of rows) individually

```
function ProtectEntradas() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheetEntradas = ss.getSheetByName('Entradas')

  // dates
  var dateRange = sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 1, sheetEntradas.getLastRow() - 2, 1); // column A
  var val = dateRange.getValues().map(d => Utilities.formatDate(d[0], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
  var date = new Date();
  var protectDateRaw = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - 14);
  var protectDate = Utilities.formatDate(protectDateRaw, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");

  // other criteria
  var crit = sheetEntradas.getRange(3, 17, sheetEntradas.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues().flat(); // column Q

  // remove protections
  sheetEntradas.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
    .forEach(protection => {
      if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    });

  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i] <= protectDate && crit[i] != '') {
      sheetEntradas.getRange(3 + i, 1, 1, 10).protect();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: it works perfect, just a question, If i want to protect the range, except some rows that column Q is empty (but its inside the range of dates protected), is there a way to edit this script to exclude those rows  ? thanks in advance

Comment: see the editing section in the answer. However, this can be very slow because each line is protected individually. To speed up, there should be two ways: using batchupdate and/or grouping the homogeneous lines in batches. In that case, open a new topic. Thx.

Comment: here is the new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256087/google-apps-script-to-protect-range-based-on-dates-and-dont-protect-a-row-if-co